# COM DLL registration failed with TFS 2010

Tags: dll, com, tfs

I have a C++ DLL project which is created in VS 2010. It is exposed as COM(ATL). I used this dll to another .NET Project as reference. C++ Project linker settings are set as follows:

```
­"Register Output" = Yes
"Per-user Redirection = Yes
```

I created a build definition to build these two projects in tfs 2010. C++ Project builds fine, but .NET project fails because the output dll of C++ project is not registered. Setting to "Per-User redirection" = false does not work. I also tried using WF activity 'InvokeProecss' to register the c++ dll using Regsrv32/batch file/my own exe etc, but I get exit code of 5. My TFS 2010 is in Windows 2008 Server R2. And I think, it's not running the process as admin.

If I generate a interop dll using tlbimp, and then I refer that interop in my .NET proejct, it works fine(oviously in tfs build, I need to add InvokeProecss to call tlb). But this is not acceptable as our general practice is to refer a COM dll directly from .NET proejct.

Can anybody please help about this?

Is there a way to run the tfs automated build activity 'InvokeProcess' as Administrator without prompting for user name/password?

Comment: Referring to a COM dll directly is not possible, tlbimp.exe is always required.  Registering COM servers on a build server is a horrible practice that can only produce registry pollution.  And isn't necessary.  Just run tlbimp.exe, no admin privileges required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the TFS Build Service runs as the "Network Service" account which is a relatively low-privilege account. Alternatively, you can configure it to run as any domain account you like. I wouldn't recommend that as a solution to the problem you described, however. I would agree with Hans that, in this case, it would be better to use the type library importer (TlbImp.exe) to "reference" your COM server from your managed assembly.

If the COM object isn't changing, you can just use the type library importer to generate an interop assembly, check that in and reference it from your .NET project. If it *is* changing, you can add a post-build step to generate the interop assembly rather than using the InvokeProcess activity. As Hans pointed out, you can't actually reference a COM object *directly* from a managed assembly. Your reference is actually causing an interop assembly to get generated at build time after resolving the reference to the registered COM server.

Comment: Thanks guys, I finally ended up running the process using one of domain user so that tfs can register the COM. I agree with Hans too, I mentioned that it works fine with tlbimp but it's just our developers who are used to compile the COM project and directly refer that to .NET project, instead of creating interop using tlbimp. Anyway..thanks a lot for all of your help